# Dynamically made html not accessible through javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var btnform = document.getElementById('clicktoadd');
var btnlist = document.getElementById('clicktoshow');
var rem = document.getElementById('main');
var cancelform;
var submit;

function addformtopage() {

  var form = document.createElement('div');
  form.setAttribute("id", "remform");
  form.innerHTML += "<div id=\"lblname\">Product Name:</div><input id=\"inpname\" type=\"text\"><div id=\"chkname\" style=\"visibility: hidden\">Enter a Product Name</div><div id=\"lbldesc\">Description:</div><textarea id=\"inpdesc\" rows=\"10\" cols=\"35\"></textarea><div id=\"chkdesc\" style=\"visibility: hidden\">Enter a Product Desciption</div><div id=\"lblprice\">Price in INR:</div><input id=\"inpprice\" type=\"number\"><div id=\"chkprice\" style=\"visibility: hidden\">Enter a Product Price</div><div id=\"lblqty\">Quantity:</div><input id=\"inpqty\" type=\"number\"><div id=\"chkqty\" style=\"visibility: hidden\">Enter a Product Quantity</div><button id=\"submitproduct\">Submit</button><button id=\"cancel\">Cancel</button>";

  cancelform = document.getElementById('cancel');
  submit = document.getElementById('submitproduct');

  document.getElementById('panel').appendChild(form);
}

function removebuttons() {
  rem.setAttribute("hidden", true);
}

function showbuttons() {
  rem.removeAttribute("hidden", false);
}


btnform.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addformtopage();
  removebuttons();
});
cancelform.addEventListener('click', function() {
  showbuttons();
});
submit.addEventListener('click', function() {

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>
    JS Form
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <p><button id="clicktoadd">Add Product</button> <button id="clicktoshow">Show List</button></p>
  </div>
  <div id="panel">

  </div>
  <div id="listing">

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am new to javascript and trying this small project in which I am adding HTML elements to HTML file. At first, the page shows two buttons. Then after we click on "Add Product", the form just added is displayed and the buttons previously showed are hidden. I have to add validation in the form but I haven't reached that step now. Right now the buttons in the form are not working as expected. Well, they are not working at all. Can someone tell me the problem in the code? Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Both of your buttons will submit a form, if you have one in your page. To prevent that, you need to either add `type="button"` in the HTML (default is `type="submit"`), or use `function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }` in your click handlers.

Comment: So, what happens when you click your buttons?

Comment: `cancelform = document.getElementById('cancel'); submit = document.getElementById('submitproduct');` will both not work unless those elements are in the DOM by the time of assignment. And both aren't.

Comment: You bind the events to the buttons before you even create them? Sort of like trying to eat a pizza before you make it.

Comment: Please check the web developers' console for errors first. The posted code reports what is going wrong on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to wait for the elements to be added to the DOM before you can query for them.

```js
var btnform = document.getElementById('clicktoadd');
var btnlist = document.getElementById('clicktoshow');
var rem = document.getElementById('main');
var cancelform;
var submit;

function addformtopage() {

  var form = document.createElement('div');
  form.setAttribute("id", "remform");
  form.innerHTML += "<div id=\"lblname\">Product Name:</div><input id=\"inpname\" type=\"text\"><div id=\"chkname\" style=\"visibility: hidden\">Enter a Product Name</div><div id=\"lbldesc\">Description:</div><textarea id=\"inpdesc\" rows=\"10\" cols=\"35\"></textarea><div id=\"chkdesc\" style=\"visibility: hidden\">Enter a Product Desciption</div><div id=\"lblprice\">Price in INR:</div><input id=\"inpprice\" type=\"number\"><div id=\"chkprice\" style=\"visibility: hidden\">Enter a Product Price</div><div id=\"lblqty\">Quantity:</div><input id=\"inpqty\" type=\"number\"><div id=\"chkqty\" style=\"visibility: hidden\">Enter a Product Quantity</div><button id=\"submitproduct\">Submit</button><button id=\"cancel\">Cancel</button>";


  // This line needs to be before...
  document.getElementById('panel').appendChild(form);

  // ...these lines
  cancelform = document.getElementById('cancel');
  submit = document.getElementById('submitproduct');
}

function removebuttons() {
  rem.setAttribute("hidden", true);
}

function showbuttons() {
  rem.removeAttribute("hidden", false);
}


btnform.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addformtopage();
  removebuttons();

  // Since cancelform & submit are created inside the addformtopage method
  // These method calls needs to be inside the event handler. 
  // Otherwise both cancelform & submit would be undefined, and you can't call methods on an undefined value
  cancelform.addEventListener('click', function() {
    showbuttons();
  });
  submit.addEventListener('click', function() {

  });
});
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <p>
    <button id="clicktoadd">Add Product</button>
    <button id="clicktoshow">Show List</button>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="panel"></div>
<div id="listing"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample how use add event listeners to buttons:

```js
document.querySelector('#clicktoadd').addEventListener('click',() => {
console.log('add button clicked')
})

document.querySelector('#clicktoshow').addEventListener('click',() => {
console.log('show button clicked')
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>
    JS Form
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <p><button id="clicktoadd">Add Product</button> <button id="clicktoshow">Show List</button></p>
  </div>
  <div id="panel">

  </div>
  <div id="listing">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

Some logic error here

```
cancelform = document.getElementById('cancel');
submit = document.getElementById('submitproduct');
document.getElementById('panel').appendChild(form);
```

`cancelform` and `submit` will return `null` because `form` is yet to added to the document.